# Injecting a new stroke color into a shape

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I have a drawing canvas (based on the EaselJS [CurveTo example](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/CurveTo.html)) and when on `mouseup` I'd like to inject a new color into the shape being rendered to the canvas. I'd also like to do it without using a filter.

BIN: https://jsbin.com/qejesuvovu/1/edit?html,output

I used to directly injecting a custom fill/stroke into the shape graphics, but in later versions of EaselJS this has stopped working.

```
marker.graphics._dirty = true;
marker.graphics._fill = new createjs.Graphics.Fill('blue');
marker.graphics._stroke = new createjs.Graphics.Stroke('blue');
```

What is the recommended way of changing the color of a shape with a single stroke color on the fly?

UPDATE:

After looking into this further it turns out I need to be able to maintain the ability clone a shape and also preserve functionality for changing the color independently.

BIN: https://jsbin.com/gorasizuho/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 0.7.0, Graphics were rearchitected to use "commands". The API for drawing is no different (except for the removal of the old `appendInstruction` API), however you can modify the properties of individual commands any time, and they will be reflected when the stage is updated.

```
var shape = new createjs.Shape();
shape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3);
var strokeCommand = shape.graphics.beginStroke("#f00").command;
shape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
```

You can modify attributes of any command:

```
strokeCommand.style = "#00f";
```

You can see a full list of commands in the Graphics docs. 
http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#property_command - each command has individual documentation: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.Stroke.html

Here is an example using commands to modify both stroke-dash offset and drawRect coordinates: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/gg8sv4cq/

You can read more here: http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/

Comment: I've just added an update to my question. I also need to be able to clone a shape while independently preserving the ability to change the stroke color. Is there a way of handling that?

Comment: This isn't currently possible. When you clone a shape (using `true` for recursive cloning), the Graphics are cloned, but they still contain references to the same instructions.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like my only option given a cloned shape would be to loop through the instructions and decide what needs to be changed based on the command type.