# EaselJS: Update shape color on property change

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs, easeljs

I am writing a simple game in JS using EaselJS. I try to keep everything object-oriented to keep in sync state of game, state of EaselJS objects and what is displayed on my canvas. I would like to have possibility to change stroke color of shapes that are displayed on canvas by changing their attributes. I've found in docs `append()` [here](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_append), but I can't get it working.

Here's what I've achieved so far:

Shape definition:

```
var bLetter = new createjs.Shape();
bLetter.graphics.append({exec: setPoweredState});
bLetter.graphics.moveTo(0, 0)
                .lineTo(0, segSize * 2)
                .arc(circSize, segSize * 2, circSize, Math.PI, Math.PI + 0.0001, true);
```

`setPoweredState` function - When i set `bLetter.powered = true`, the line color should change:

```
setPoweredState = function(ctx, shape) {
    if(shape.powered) {
        shape.color = consts.COLOR_LINE_ACTIVE;
    } else {
        shape.color = consts.COLOR_LINE_INACTIVE;
    }
    shape.graphics.beginStroke(shape.color).setStrokeStyle(consts.STROKE_SIZE, 'round', 'round');

}
```

When I set `bLetter.powered = true` and I check `bLetter.color` it seems that the function is executed - the `bLetter.color` property changes. However, the `bLetter` object on canvas is not updated. What's more, it's not drawn at all - probably I am using `append()` in incorrect way. What am I missing?

BTW: I omit the code with initializing `createjs.Stage` on canvas and adding `bLetter` as it's child, I don't think it's an issue, the shape is drawn correctly, only color won't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are continually appending new stroke / strokestyle commands to the end of the graphics queue, so they have no effect on the preceding paths.

The easiest approach in my opinion would be to save off the command as Lanny suggested, and modify its style in your `setPoweredState` method.

Here's an example of the above, implement with minimal modifications to your approach:
https://jsfiddle.net/u4o4hahw/

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Also, thanks for answering why my approach was invalid. Nothing better than answer from library creator himself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `append`, consider just storing off commands to modify.

Here is another question that I answered outlining how it works: [Injecting a new stroke color into a shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534887/injecting-a-new-stroke-color-into-a-shape/33536016#33536016), and here is a blog post: http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/

Basically, you can store any command, then change its properties later:

```
var cmd = shape.graphics.beginFill("red").command;
shape.graphics.otherInstructionsHere();
// Later
cmd.style = "blue";
```

Here is a link to the docs on the Fill command used in the sample code: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.Fill.html

Comment: Hi, I know about that, but I want to automate a bit more if that is possible. Moreover if I usr command I have to store commands for different objects separately, otherwise I will change all objects' colours at once.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I will have another look at your question.